# Generating App on Remote Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A friend of mine runs hosting services and iam looking to get my rails 3 App hosted on his service.
My App is very small.
The Question is, is it a good idea to build the App right on the server which i want to host?
There's command line and everything else needed to work remotely.
Any opinions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience it's much more practical to build the app locally, and then to deploy it to the server using git. This way you can keep working on it even when you are not connected to the remote server.

Comment: Thanks picardo.In this case, the app has only two views.I was thinking that maybe deploying it after building locally would be too much of a work for such a small App.

Comment: It's your choice, but putting the app in version control can be useful to you in the future. You can use git hooks to run bundler after deployment, so you don't have to go back and forth between local and remote environments. It's a little more work initially, but it's good practice.